# Graph Databases' Implementation

Tags: database, graph

I am having trouble visualizing a Graph Database.
Visualizing an RDBMS is really very simple and I was able to understand from the first tutorial itself when I started learning it some 4-5 years ago.
But I am not able to understand Graph Databases.

I am also unable to get any good links on this topic, hence posting this question here.

Specifically, I am looking for the following:

1. Some really simple book/link on Graph Dbs
2. Atleast some knowledge on the implementation details of a Graph DB (I hope all Graph DBs would be having atleast a few basic things in common).

Thanks a lot in advance guys,

Answer (score 3):

[Protoge](http://protege.stanford.edu/) is your best bet to get started understanding ontologies.

[IsaVis](http://www.w3.org/2001/11/IsaViz/) is a pretty common tool for visualizing you db.

[Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) and [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) are you best bets for implementations (both in java) but for prototyping python rocks and [rdflib](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the must use tool there.

There are plenty of others out there but those are my suggested entry vehicles.  YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j did a quite good job for me explaining the concept. Also starting with it to test is quite easy to do. You could start here:

http://neo4j.org/learn/

Comment: [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqvDSioHYq8&feature=relmfu) helped me alot understanding the concepts of a graph db.